# What should be my response body in raml if i am sending hashmap as response?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

I am using sharepoint connector in my api and able to receive response in form of hashmap, i want to send the hashmap response as it is as output, what should i do?
(Note: i have set my raml body response as application/java)

I tried setting multiple body responses in raml , e.g- application/json, apllication/java
But was able to receive error stating invalid data format

Comment: Why would you want to send Java serialized objects in a REST API? This looks to be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You should provide more clarity into what are you trying to achieve, what is the original problem you are trying to resolve.